# What's the lowest number R will present before rounding to 0?

Tags: r, statistics, p-value

I'm doing some statistical analysis with R software (bootstrapped Kolmogorov-Smirnov tests) of very large data sets, meaning that my p values are all incredibly small. I've Bonferroni corrected for the large number of tests that I've performed meaning that my alpha value is also very small in order to reject the null hypothesis.

The problem is, R presents me with p values of 0 in some cases where the p value is presumably so small that it cannot be presented (these are usually for the very large sample sizes). While I can happily reject the null hypothesis for these tests, the data is for publication, so I'll need to write p < ..... but I don't know what the lowest reportable values in R are?

I'm using the `ks.boot` function in case that matters.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This will depend. Take a look at `sprintf()`, the `options()` for `digits` and `scipen`.

Comment: .... and you can also take a look at `.Machine`

Comment: Practically `p < 1e-6` is fine - p-values smaller than that are likely to be meaningless anyway because of minor violations in the assumptions of the test you're using.

Answer (score 4):

`.Machine$double.xmin` gives you the smallest non-zero normalized floating-point number. On most systems that's 2.225074e-308. However, I don't believe this is a sensible limit.

Instead I suggest that in `Matching::ks.boot` you change the line

`ks.boot.pval <- bbcount/nboots` to

`ks.boot.pval <- log(bbcount)-log(nboots)` and work on the log-scale.

**Edit:**

You can use `trace` to modify the function.

Step 1: Look at the function body, to find out where to add additional code.

```
as.list(body(ks.boot))
```

You'll see that element 17 is `ks.boot.pval <- bbcount/nboots`, so we need to add the modified code directly after that.

Step 2: `trace` the function.

```
trace (ks.boot, quote(ks.boot.pval <- log(bbcount)-log(nboots)), at=18)
```

Step 3: Now you can use `ks.boot` and it will return the logarithm of the bootstrap p-value as `ks.boot.pvalue`. Note that you cannot use `summary.ks.boot` since it calls `format.pval`, which will not show you negative values.

Step 4: Use `untrace(ks.boot)` to remove the modifications.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. When I do this I get the error:

`Error in ks2.boot(x, HIdata2[2:length(HIdata), 1], nboots = 50, alternative = "two.sided",  : 
  could not find function "Mks.test" `

Comment: Thanks for the detailed step-by-step guide @Roland ! However, I'm now just getting `-Inf` rather than `0` which is still not quite what I need.

Comment: @N.M. That value is absolutely correct. `exp(-Inf)` is zero and you get that value because `bbcount` is zero. You could try to increase the number of bootstrap iterations and hope to get a small number of successes. You could also try to calculate the probability to get zero in the bootstrap for a given probability. However, these problems should show you that for extremely small probabilities the actual value doesn't matter much and you need to spend a lot of effort (i.e., computation time) to estimate these small p-values with good precision.

Comment: If your probability is something like 1e-8, that means the value of the `nboots` parameter must be (much) larger than 1e8 to get a robust estimate of the p-value. I am beginning to doubt that your bootstrap p-values can become small enough that you need to consider floating point precision. Instead you need to consider the underlying statistical issue of reliability of these small bootstrap p-values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether `ks.boot` has methods in the packages `Rmpfr` or `gmp`  but if it does, or you feel like rolling your own code, you can work with arbitrary precision and arbitrary size numbers.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still an R (and coding) novice, could you explain more about how this works / how to do this? Are you suggesting I edit the `ks.boot` function code to incorporate `mpfr` numbers?

Comment: @N.M. Hi, and welcome to `R` .  Yep, that's basically what I was suggesting.  The package `Rmpfr` has methods for a lot of functions, so it's possible `ks.boot` will "just work" with `mpfr` inputs.  If it doesn't, you'd have to find out which lines of code don't work and rewrite them with `mpfr`-compatible functions.  A daunting task, in all probability.